# React native F2 chart does not show up on android

Tags: android, react-native, f2-chart

Does anyone knows why it does not show up on android? it works perfectly fine on iOS. I'm using this lib btw https://github.com/aloneszjl/react-native-f2chart. In example, it seems to work with both iOS and android, but I can't get it to work on android. Any help would be appreciated

```
const HomeTab = () => {
      const data = [
        {
          date: '2017-06-05',
          value: 116,
        },
        {
          date: '2017-06-06',
          value: 129,
        },
        {
          date: '2017-06-07',
          value: 135,
        },
      ];

      const initScript = data => `
      (function(){
          chart =  new F2.Chart({
              id: 'chart',
              pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio,
          });
          chart.source(${JSON.stringify(data)}, {
          value: {
          tickCount: 5,
          min: 0
          },
          date: {
          type: 'timeCat',
          range: [0, 1],
          tickCount: 3
          }
          });
          chart.tooltip({
          custom: true,
          showXTip: true,
          showYTip: true,
          snap: true,
          crosshairsType: 'xy',
          crosshairsStyle: {
          lineDash: [2]
          }
          });
          chart.axis('date', {
          label: function label(text, index, total) {
          var textCfg = {};
          if (index === 0) {
              textCfg.textAlign = 'left';
          } else if (index === total - 1) {
              textCfg.textAlign = 'right';
          }
          return textCfg;
          }
          });
          chart.line().position('date*value');
          chart.render();
      })();

      `;

    return(
    <View style={{ height: 200, width: 400}}>
         <Chart
            style={{flex: 1, width: 400}}
            initScript={initScript(data)}
         />
    </View>
    )
}
```

[image]